# TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

EDIT: This issue has been resolved

I am getting the following error while trying to execute the !fish command in discord:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shane\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:38:43)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\shane\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\shane\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\shane\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\shane\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\shane\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\shane\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\shane\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

All the other commands seem to be working fine. Just "fishCommand" is giving the error. fishCommand is defined in fish.js

Main.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('DiscordBot is online!')
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'yeet'){
        client.commands.get('yeet').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'modtoggle'){
        client.commands.get('modtoggle').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'fish'){
        client.commands.get('fishCommand').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'backpack'){
        client.commands.get('backpack').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login('Discord Bot token here');
```

fish.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// embeds that are picked at random
const rawFish = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#0077be')
.setTitle('You caught a raw fish!')
.setDescription('It has been added to your backpack.')
.setThumbnail('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft-computer/images/7/77/Raw_Fish.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340?cb=20130815172634')

const rawSalmon = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#0077be')
.setTitle('You caught a raw salmon!')
.setDescription('It has been added to your backpack.')
.setThumbnail('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft/images/f/fd/RawSalmonOldTexture.png/revision/latest/window-crop/width/200/x-offset/0/y-offset/0/window-width/201/window-height/200?cb=20200519072953')

const pufferfish = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#0077be')
.setTitle('You caught a pufferfish!')
.setDescription('It has been added to your backpack.')
.setThumbnail('https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft_gamepedia/images/0/02/Pufferfish_%28item%29_JE5_BE2.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/150?cb=20191230044452')

const tropicalFish = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#0077be')
.setTitle('You caught a tropical fish!')
.setDescription('It has been added to your backpack.')
.setThumbnail('https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft_gamepedia/images/a/ad/Tropical_Fish_JE2_BE2.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/150?cb=20191230044408')

const fishTypes = [rawFish, rawSalmon, pufferfish, tropicalFish];

module.exports = {
    name: 'fishCommand',
    description: "Lets the user fish",
    execute(message, args){

        //sends a random embed from fishTypes
        message.channel.send(fishTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fishTypes.length)]);
        
       
        }
    }

    var backpack = 0;

 module.exports = {
    name: 'backpack',
    description: "Lets the user see their backpack",
    execute(message, args){

        message.channel.send('Your backpack has ' + backpack + ' fish in it.');
           
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command file **(fish.js)** name should be the same as **what is the file the client getting.**

```js
client.commands.get('fishCommand').execute(message, args);
```

The file name should be **'fishCommand.js'** OR you should write it as `get('fish')`.

```js
client.commands.get('fish').execute(message, args);
```

`execute` is undefined because your client don't know where it is located at.

Comment: Actually, the collection has each command mapped with the command name *from the `name` property in the file* as the key; file names are not an issue.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help, but this did not seem to fix the issue. I renamed the file to "fishCommand.js" as you said, and I still got the same error. Any other ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: @Lioness100 alright i don't really understand alot about of javascript, nor am i a pro lol.
@Dashanesta can you try to remove the `module.exports` that executes the `backpack ` command? and then make a file for the `backpack` command instead.

Comment: @Hons thank you for the suggestion, I will try it later today when I have a chance.

Comment: This has fixed the issue! Thank you guys, I really appreciate the help!